# Are there anywhere instructions explaining how to troubleshoot sound problems on the Ubuntu desktops?

Tags: sound

I would like to have a general list of steps I can do to troubleshoot problems with sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

The first step on a current (10.04) distribution should be to run:

```
ubuntu-bug audio
```

in a terminal or after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.