# No sound Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / Windows 11 Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, sound, soundcard

I have recently done my first dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows. However, now I don't have sound with my speakers. I have tried all the troubleshooting steps I could find online, however nothing seems to work.

Using bluetooth headset, the sound works, but the speakers do not work.

They are recognised I believe, the microphone also works, but the speakers do not produce sound.

**Screenshot from Sound tab in settings:**

[image]

When running Windows 11, I do not experience any of these issues.

My system: asus zenbook 15 oled um3504da-ma204w

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sound not working in ASUS Zenbook OLED](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470253/sound-not-working-in-asus-zenbook-oled)

Comment: I have previously tried this. This did not solve my problem.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2033/are-there-anywhere-instructions-explaining-how-to-troubleshoot-sound-problems-on) and file a bug report.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title the green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue;

The problem was that I had to update to a new kernel version. Was using 6.5.x and upgraded to 6.7.6.

This has fully solved my issue.

Comment: Click the check on the left side of your answer to mark it as solved.